# Restrict Google OAuth Client to only App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

We have an App Engine application build in Python using Endpoints. Access to it is restricted.

We have software that connects with the App Engine using a service account. With this service account we can also access Google Cloud Storage to create buckets.

Now we want to allow access to the App Engine (and not the Cloud Storage) for specific clients who will write their own software. So their software will be their end-user.

What do we have to create and share with the client so their software can authenticate only with the App Engine?

A service account does not seem possible since this allows access to the Cloud Storage.

Comment: are you using the service account to talk to Cloud Endpoints ?

Comment: Yes, our application is using the service account.